# dlsym function return type

Tags: dlopen, dlsym

i am loading libslabhidtouart.so file using dlopen() without any error but when i am calling a function using dlsym() ,I got no such process  error

here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
typedef unsigned int DWORD;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef int HID_UART_STATUS;
    void *handle;
    HID_UART_STATUS (*cosine)( DWORD*,WORD,WORD);
    //typedef void (*simple_demo_function)(void);
    char *error;

   handle = dlopen("libslabhidtouart.so.1.0", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", dlerror());
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

   /* Writing: cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
       would seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves
       casting from "void *" to a function pointer undefined.
       The assignment used below is the POSIX.1-2003 (Technical
       Corrigendum 1) workaround; see the Rationale for the
       POSIX specification of dlsym(). */

   *(void **) (&cosine) =  dlsym(handle, "HidUart_GetNumDevices");

   if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "  %s\n", error);
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    getchar();
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
    }
```

/**** return type of function HidUart_GetNumDevices  is int,so is there any casting problem or my method signature is wrong or what else plz guide me,i am no good at c .

Comment: And what is (or was) your question? `dlsym` returns `void *`; you can typecast it to some other pointer type, like `int (*)(uint32_t *, uint16_t, uint16_t)` -- if not directly then in two steps: `myfunptr= (int (*)(uint32_t *, uint16_t, uint16_t))(intptr_t)dlsym(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I also got strange "No such process" errors, yet already directly upon a <kbd>dlopen()</kbd> call within OpenSSL:

```
2675996:error:25066067:lib(37):func(102):reason(103):dso_dlfcn.c:187:filename(./engine_pkcs11.dll): No such process
```

It turned out that the referenced DLL (or .so file) exists, but has a dependency on some other library (<kbd>cygp11-2.dll</kbd> in my case) that could not be resolved in the context of the application's process (taking into account its PATH environment variable setting). In this case, use <kbd>ldd</kbd> (or <kbd>cygcheck.exe</kbd> if applicable) to see if all dependencies are correctly resolved.

So the "no such process" error message returned by <kbd>dlerror()</kbd> can be quite misleading.